# continously monitor ip_conntrack in order to monitor browsing on NAT router

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat

So, I have a server that also does NAT (masquerading) for my LAN, and forwards all internet traffic to a gateway.

I need to know who in my LAN is visiting what websites. I don't want to go the whole SQUID proxy route.

I (very surprisingly?) couldn't find any software that does this easily.

AFAICT, /proc/net/ip_conntrack should have all information I need, because all my LAN's connections go through the NAT.

So I hacked together a small script that simply DNS-resolves all the entries in ip_conntrack, and log them.

My plan was to simply do a 'tail -f /proc/net/ip_conntrack |my_script.pl', and be done with it, but tail-f doesn't seem to work on that file? It dumps out a lot of lines, and then stops.

How can I get every new connection that is NAT'ed on my server in realtime? Have I missed a ready-made software that simply tells me who on my LAN is talking to which server on the internet, via this NAT?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but why was this downvoted? It seems pertinent?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I suspect  you are probably being downvoted because your approach is going to give you mostly worthless results. Heck, just setting and using up a local DNS server that logs queries would probably be far more effective, and wouldn't be so hacky.

Comment: Would iftop work? With DNS resolution on + showing source IP I think this would work: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/

Answer (score 2):

The `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` is not a log file that `tail -f` would work on.  It is more like an API that returns the current state of memory when queried.

To get the same results you could probably add netfilter(iptables) rule that logged the traffic you what to know about.  Then just tail your syslog file that  those particular kernel messages go to.

Though in my opinion this is more or less pointless since a reverse DNS of the IPs used isn't going to be close to reliable for telling you what people are going to.  A huge portion of the internet now on CDNs, or cloud services like Amazon/Azure/Google/etc. Your reverse DNS for anything big will probably just tell you that lots of content you visit is hosted on one of the many cloud services.

Comment: Yes, I just ran some tests, and I just stumbled upon man IPs with completely meaningless reverse DNS lookups. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

There is also available a nice  [netstat-nat](http://tweegy.nl/projects/netstat-nat/) tool which displays NAT connections, managed by netfilter/iptables. The program reads its information from `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` or `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`, which is the temporary conntrack-storage of netfilter.

You just need to take care of logging its output and monitoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not personally done-so, it should be possible to use the `NFTC` (netfilter conntrack) plugin from the [`ulogd` 2.x](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) package from the Linux netfilter project to do this.

There is an extensive guide [here](https://home.regit.org/2014/02/logging-connection-tracking-event-with-ulogd/).

ulogd 2.x is packaged in Debian and derivatives as the `ulogd2` package.